# Error:Upgrade MVC4 to MVC5 in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting below error after upgrade my project from MVC4 to MVC5. I followed [How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

`Assembly 'WebServices.WebApi.External, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Upgrade all of your NuGet packages.

Comment: I did, Which Nuget Package has System.Web.Http

Comment: I'm not sure.  Select that reference in your project and look at its full path.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll

Comment: Hmm; that should be v5.  Try cleaning the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, it was due to me using the

_bin_deployableAssemblies

This folder had the System.Web.Http in it at version 4. I deleted this folder and it worked

Answer (score 4):

I also follow that article without full success at start but

To fix this "simple" create new web mvc project and save it
then open web.config, web.config from views, packages.config, and .csproj in notepad

then open your project and look at difference in entry for version numbers of files
e.g. in packages you should see

```xml
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

but you can have

```xml
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.x.x.x" targetFramework="net40" />
```

in web.config

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

but you can have

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

in .csproj

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

but you can have

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

replace all with newer values

after that do Ctrl+Shift+B
and in nuget console update all packages by comand Update-Package

for me this work finally

Answer (score 1):

You should check all references of WebServices.WebApi.External project. One of them may still use System.Web.Http version 4. Or, try binding it explicitly in web.config

```xml
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: After upgrading a MVC project I started getting the above error. After actually READING the error I found that it was the reference to the web project in my unit test project that was causing the problem. After upgrading the test project with a matching version, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing the System.Web.Http.WebHost.  You can install by using nuget and search for WebHost. This is the exact link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost/5.1.0

you can also install it from the Package Manager Console:
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved by uninstalling the old AttributeRouting package with Nuget. Of course, it is not needed anymore.

This was in a unit testing project, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed the troublesome binding from the *Web.config* file, that solved the issue.

Backup you *web.config*, then simply erase `dependentAssembly` element containing an `assemblyIdentity` element with the name `System.Web.Http`.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

It worked for me instantly.