# GlobalConfiguration does not contain a definition for Configure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm attempting to create an ASP.NET MVC site that uses Database First Entity Framework.

I'm using creating a new MVC 5 site in **Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 3**, then adding an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** from which I choose **EF Designer from database**.

After that, I create a connection string, select the tables to generate the framework, and all is well.

However when I compile it, I receive this error

> 'MyModel.GlobalConfiguration' does not contain a definition for
>   'Configure'

This is in **Global.asax.cs** and errors here

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

`GlobalConfiguration` is automatically generated with the added entity framework for `MyModel`. It certainly doesn't have a Configure method.

```
public partial class GlobalConfiguration
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public long CurrentUSN { get; set; }
    public string DBVersion { get; set; }
    public long CurrentFile { get; set; }
}
```

I followed all of the answers here [GlobalConfiguration.Configure() not present after Web API 2 and .NET 4.5.1 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226715/globalconfiguration-configure-not-present-after-web-api-2-and-net-4-5-1-migra) but none worked. It's a slightly different situation as this isn't an upgrade but is instead a clean project.

All Extensions and NuGet packages are up to date. I've even deleted the generated entity and reinstalled all NuGet packages to see if that helped, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Open the `Package Manager Console` for the Project with the error.
2. Type in `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` and hit Enter.
3. Rebuild your Project.

Comment: We can also install the same from NuGet package manager UI too

Comment: I tried but not worked for me, I used Net40 Application,Is there any changes in NET40

Answer (score 8):

It looks like there is some sort of namespace conflict with the generated code. I'm fairly weary about this change, but everything has worked thus far.

Apparently `GlobalConfiguration` refers to `MyModel.GlobalConfiguration`.

However it's really looking for `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration`

I switched this and all is working. What a hassle

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, what a HUGE hassle.  You would think MS could do a better job with package names and/or keep them in sync with one another.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Make sure the files in your Team Explorer, if perform checkin;

2 - Check for old files in "packages" concerning the dll WebAPI such as the folder "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3" folder, if there are clear;

3 - After leaving everything clean install the project;

**Good luck!!!!!**