# WebAPI deployed to IIS, gives 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I'm trying to create a simple WebAPI in ASP.NET. I put it in IIS. When I try to browse the site it's all good:

[image]

But when I try to get a result from the API, I get this error:

[image]

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
```

WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You host it on the application accessed by `/api`, so you need an additional `/api` to match the routing:

```
http://localhost:6060/api/api/Product
```

If you don't want that, then either give the `api` site a more sensible name, remove the `api/` from the route, or both.

Comment: That's because your controller is called `ProductController`, singular, so you need Product, not Products.

Comment: Yeah so what did your research show up? Is the config you show the entire config, or did you cut some lines from it? Did you [register WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621825/asp-net-mvc-webapi-404-error) and [install the WebHost package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450105/globalconfiguration-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-configure)?

Comment: its the entire config and i didn't do anything of the above

Comment: Do you now want me to tell you that you should? :)

Comment: I just followed the following guide: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api, and it seems to worked for him and there wasnt any reference to what you mentioned

Comment: @Pachu so you got it figured out now? What did solve the issue eventually?