# dotnet core 2.2 web api added as application is not working in IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis-10

I have created two projects. One is front end which is developed by using angular and backend is developed in dotnet core web api. Now i tried to publish into Web server (IIS). I have created website and mapped to frontend project and then i added web api as add application. Now i tried to access webapi but it is not working. By seeing physical path is changed wrongly.

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: Are you sure that the root `/` path has a controller associated with it? 404 is a normal response for API's if there are no resources registered

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: You can check it in the sourcecode

Comment: You could setup your frontend with the IIS site address and check if it works?

Comment: can we connect privately? i can explain my problem in detail

Comment: front end & back end is hosted successfully. when i invoke any controller action method that time web api physical path is mapping to wrong location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231501/discussion-between-venkateswaran-r-and-maartendev).

Comment: There are many reasons for 404 error, can you share a screenshot of your error page? I think this error may be caused by your routing, you can refer to this link for the same problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275341/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275341/13336642).