# how to fix this error WebApiConfig in Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4

There's a great thread running here:
[How to add Web API to an existing ASP.NET MVC (5) Web Application project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067296/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-5-web-application-project/)

Unfortunately, for me is having an error on WebApiConfig in Global.asax, so how can i fix this error i even installed nugets.

> The name 'WebApiConfig' does not exist in the current context

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
 public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // WebAPI when dealing with JSON & JavaScript!
        // Setup json serialization to serialize classes to camel (std. Json format)
        var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have checked please add webapiconfig class code.

Comment: I feel that you have namespace issue.

Comment: @MairajAhmad it fine now it was namespace

Comment: yes that's why i was asking for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you copied code from other project , you are merging web api in existing mvc project so many time two project have different namespace so you have to add namespace or change namespace of webapiconfig.