# Can ASP.Net MVC 5 be integrated with ASP.Net Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, asp.net-web-api, integration

Can ASP.Net Web API 2 be integrated on top of ASP.Net MVC 5 so that next ASP.Net Web API 2 can be used by UI layer e.g. Ext.js 6 (MVVM)?  Essentially we would have (?)

ASP.NET MVC 5 <=> ASP.Net Web API 2 <=> UI Layer e.g. Ext.JS 6 (MVVM)

Do I need to rewrite ASP.Net MVC 5 layer and how?

Cheers,

Learner.For.Ever

Comment: Sure. You can do add Web api 2 controllers to your MVC5 project.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067296/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-5-web-application-project

Comment: Thanks to both of you for comments and a link!