# Expand MVC API to all controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I added the AspNet.WebAPI to my existing MVC project with help from this post:

[How to add Web API to an existing ASP.NET MVC (5) Web Application project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067296/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-5-web-application-project)

It basically adds the following controller:

```
public class APIController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
...
```

And this in the App_Start:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // WebAPI when dealing with JSON & JavaScript!
        // Setup json serialization to serialize classes to camel (std. Json format)
        var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new     Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        }
    }
}
```

This works, but for just for mysite/api/API
How do I expand this to work with the rest of my existing controllers (for example mysite/api/CLIENTs)?

From looking at the code, it seems it should just work.  I even tried putting "Get" functions in the other controllers but no luck.  Actually I don't know why /API works--is it reading the file name of the controller?

So basically, I am looking for advice on where to go next--do I put code in each individual controller, or put many calls in my existing "APIController", or neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller it added is just an example of a WebAPI controller.  You can add more.  For example:

```
public class ClientsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        // return a collection of clients
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Since they inherit from different base classes, you'll need to keep your MVC controllers and API controllers separate.  So just add API controllers for your API methods.