# ApiController not working with 404 expection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller that I derived from System.Web.Http.ApiController(Used Nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3).

I have used RoutePrefix on the controller class and Route Attribute on the Action.

I have two routes configured. One within WebAPiConfig(HttpRouteCollection) and other in RouteConfig(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection)

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I hit a request from Postman. I get 404 error code. And strange thing is the stack trace is:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/api/Account/IsAuthorized&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Below is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance is authorized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>send whether the user is authorized or not</returns>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("IsAuthorized")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage IsAuthorized()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        ////return true;
    }
}
```

Global.asax order of registration

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(HttpConfiguration.Config);
        WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration.Config);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Why the framework is trying to initialize controller via System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance

In the same API project, I have another controller that is devired by System.Web.Mvc.Controller and that is working good.

Any pointers will help me a lot.

Comment: Can you share your controller code too?

Comment: @AlenGenzić I have edited the original post along with the namespaces

Comment: Are you sending a `GET` (not a `POST` or anything else) from Postman?

Comment: @JLe Sending a Get request as the action(IsAuthorized) supports Get

Comment: Can you share code from `Application_Start()` from `Global.asax.cs`?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067296/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-5-web-application-project. I hope it could help.

Comment: @Karan I have added the Global.asax code in the original post. I think the ordering is correct.

Comment: @user2861226 It seems perfect. I thought `WebApiConfig.Register` might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just before define your routes add this :

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing)

Comment: This is already defined in the WebApiConfig's Register method.

Comment: @user2861226 and you have added `config.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`?

Comment: No, I have added config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); though. Going to try out MapMvcAttributeRoutes as well

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

instead of

```
WebApiConfig.Register(Orbit.WebApi.Extensions.Startup.Config);
```

worked for me. I have to figure out what is the real difference between these two lines when it comes to WebAPI controllers.

I remember I read at some place that this is just an improvement. But it can make this much big a difference, that I did not know.

Will really appreciate if anyone can throw in some light on this.