# What is causing the error that swagger is already in the route collection for Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I installed Swagger in my ASP.Net MVC Core project and it is documenting my API beautifully.

My co-worker asked me to install it in a full framework 4.6.1 project so I've done the following.

In Package Console Manager run:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

To get your Test Web API controller working:
1) Comment this out in the WebApi.config:

```
// config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
// config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Now this URL:
http://localhost:33515/api/Test
brings back XML:

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>value1</string>
<string>value2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

In Global.asax Register() I call:

```
 SwaggerConfig.Register();
```

In AppStart.Swagger.Config Register() I put:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {     
       var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1.0", "HRSA CHAFS");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                })
              .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {});
    }

    private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        var path = String.Format(@"{0}bin\Services.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        return path;

    }
}
```

Now I get this error:
"A route named 'swagger_docsswagger/docs/{apiVersion}' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique."

I've been stuck on this for hours.
How do you get rid of this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: clean solution delete all bin/release folders and try to build again

Answer (score 44):

This can happen when you re-name your .NET assembly. A DLL with the previous assembly name will be present in your bin folder. This causes the swagger error.

Delete your bin folder and re-build your solution.
This resolves the swagger error.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me

Answer (score 28):

Swagger config uses pre-application start hook, so you don't need to call `SwaggerConfig.Register()` explicitly. Otherwise `Register` method is called twice.

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]
```

Comment: I inherited code and one of my coworkers created the swaggerconfig.cs file. This is why I had two register lines. I commented out one config file and the run time error went away.

Answer (score 2):

in my case i added another project as refrence  and that other project has swagger too.
i remove that refrence and move needed code to new  project.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting the SwaggerConfig.cs file from the App_Start folder as I had already created it manually.
Take a look at this link, here also has more useful information:

[A route named 'DefaultApi' is already in the route collection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102079/a-route-named-defaultapi-is-already-in-the-route-collection-error)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the error occurs when you add reference to another project and that project is a service and it occurs on the SwaggerConfig of the referenced project. Removing project reference usually solve the problem, if you need to share classes I suggest you to create a specific project as Class Library and add its reference to both your services